# Is there anything else to do Audio in 92khz to 192khz?

Tags: java, python, c, lua, ada

I spend lot of time researching/finding a best developer friendly framework or libraries for cross platform to deal with solid/accurate/lipsync sort of audio solution. Still could not find one which can be used for cross platform.

I tried GStreamer (was the best one) but it is best for linux as it covers CELT/Vorbis/Speex (encoder/decoder), GStreamer does the great job for Linux. But porting Gstreamer to Windows and Mac platform is not friendly, and lot of restrictions, and facing lot of problems, where i found myself its not the best way to build better application, the way i know about audio.

Is there any audio libraries or framework which can handle lowest latency for any cross platform ? No matter what language it is C/ADA/LUA/Python/Java..., to study from that libraries. To build my own freedom of audio quality over internet for musicians/conversation peer 2 peer in RTP method to have maximum range of 192 khz.

Expecting experts, advise.

```
My project is:
1. Peer 1 - playing electrical guiter from UK (london)
2. Peer 2 - playing drums from USA (new york)
3. Peer 3 - playing bass guiter from UK (luton)
```

And Peer 4 is listening, and doing recording in Holland (amsterdam)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd be curious as how you deal with network latency. Do you plan to use prediction ?

Comment: Network latency is not a big issue, if you know what you are up to. You can have dedicated leased clear fiber or even anything (ex: MPLS network etc etc) . Main issue is getting out RAW audio from hardware and transfer it without losing anything of it, from A to B. Which i belive RtAudio can allow me. Want to give thanks again to @georg , if i get success. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's C++ and i don't know if it fully fits your bill, but [RtAudio](http://www.music.mcgill.ca/~gary/rtaudio/) provides a nice and easy to use cross-platform wrapper for realtime audio output & input.

Comment: Many Thanks, Great libraries, just started working, and it works, any idea if it has already any related encoder/decoder ?

Comment: @Stackfan: No, i haven't dealt with audio en-/decoding yet. A new question will hopefully help you out :)

Answer (score 1):

[murgaLua](http://www.murga-projects.com/murgaLua/index.html) comes with a binding to [proteaAudio](http://viremo.eludi.net/proteaAudio/index.html) if you want to have something to be up and running quickly...
It's cross platform Windows-Mac-Linux ;)

Comment: WOW, this is great, its better then RtAudio. I just hacked today all RtAudio, it looks like University projects are always dead. You dont have support or community. MurgaLua/proteaAudio is very good too. :)